# Unable to find or serve resource, primefaces.css, from library, primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, jsf-2, primefaces

I have an application developed(among others) with Primefaces 3.0.M4/RC1-Snapshot, server Tomcat 6.0.33. On my computer everything works just fine but if I want to access it through a network I'm getting this exception:

```
    WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, primefaces.js, from library, primefaces.
    Nov 25, 2011 9:38:08 AM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
    WARNING:
    ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error

    WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, layout/layout.js, from library, primefaces.
    Nov 25, 2011 5:08:16 PM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
    WARNING: 
    ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error

WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, primefaces.css, from library, primefaces.
Nov 25, 2011 5:13:21 PM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
WARNING: 
ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error

        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:369)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:439)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:354)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:392)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:381)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:89)
        at java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl.write(Channels.java:275)
        at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:283)
        at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:125)
        at org.primefaces.application.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:99)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:506)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at creazione.exception.MyFilter.doFilter(MyFilter.java:50)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat60AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat60AgentValve.java:30)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:760)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:439)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:354)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:784)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:593)
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:560)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:364)
```

Comment: That can happen if the client aborted the request on the main page by for example pressing `Esc` or navigating away or repeatedly pressing F5, etcetera. Is this also what is happening? Or does this also happen when you gently wait until the browser is completely finished with loading the page? Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039815/jsf1064-unable-to-find-or-serve-resource-warning-on-jsf-2-0

Comment: Yes, it's also happening when you just wait - the components are rendered very badly sometimes...

Comment: Are you or the server behind a proxy?

Comment: I'd blame the proxy. But curiously enough, I'd contact the proxy admin about this issue to see what he can tell about this based on the proxy's logs.

Comment: @BalusC You see, I work in Romania and the proxy logs are somewhere in India or maybe Italy and it's hard to make them understand that I want to know the proxy logs only for development purpose. I'll see, though, what I can do. Thank you!